# jBPM6: using rules contained in a separate jar artifact

Tags: java, maven, drools, jbpm

I'm trying to implement a jBPM6 project containing both processes and rules.

One thing I would like to achieve (if it is possible) is to develop a separate artifact containing only the rules definitions, and then referencing this jar into the processes' project via maven, being able to execute the rules from my processes.

I implemented this solution, but when I execute one of the process that uses the rules none of the rules is fired. To verify that there were no implementation problems I put the rules definition files into the processes' project directly, and it worked in this way.

So, it is like the system is not able to load the rules definitions when they are contained into another jar archive. Does anyone knows how to solvemy problem, and if what I want to achieve is even possible in jBPM6? Thank you very much.

Comment: Define the dependencies between kjar. In kmodule.xml of each kjar define KnowledgeBase name and in parent kjar include all kbase, like as:
`<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule"; xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">;
<kbase name="kbase-top" default="true" eventProcessingMode="stream" equalsBehavior="identity" packages="*" includes="kbase1,kbase2">
<ksession name="ksession-top" type="stateful" default="true" clockType="realtime"/>
</kbase>
</kmodule>`

Comment: Thank you very much Abhijit, that worked! I was able to make the rules fire, as i put a debug print in the conditions and inthe consequences and they print correctly. There is still something missing thou: as output, my rules set a global String variable, and when i try to read it into my process the result is null. The code I use to read the global is the following: kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().getGlobal("globalName"). Could it be due to the fact that the ksession name defined in the rules kmodule is different from the one defined in the processes' kmodule?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with [repository1](https://github.com/abhijithumbe/repository1) and its working fine. I can see global variables are accessible across different projects. Go through repository1

Comment: What do you mean with "Go through repository1"? I'm developing through the JBoss developer studio, not on the workbench.

Comment: Its for working for me, so it should for you as well. Compare provided project with your to see if you are doing something different.